# how apps login user via FaceID

Tags: swift, security, authentication, authorization, face-id

Several uses cases where apps are loggin users in. [Link](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-use-face-id-to-sign-into-apps-on-iphone-x)

Now the relevant code form [apple site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id)

```
let reason = "Log in to your account"
context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in

    if success {

        // Move to the main thread because a state update triggers UI changes.
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.state = .loggedin
        }

    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")

        // Fall back to a asking for username and password.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Question is how do you identity on the backend who the user is once authenticated after FaceID after this line

```
self.state = .loggedin
```

Are we saving user's email address or password somewhere or do we have a token or refresh token that identifiers the user for relevant data access or are we storing username and passwords in keychain?

How is it supposed to work after FaceID authentication?